# PHP arrays 2 dimensional, how to check if 2 values are inside and position of them

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two dimensional array as follows:

```
$array2dimension = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 12:00
            [box] => 3
            [user] => Laura
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] => 14:00
            [box] => 3
            [user] => John
        )

)
```

Currently I have two values, but sometimes I have much more, where two of them has [box] = '3', but different [time] (12:00 and 14:00)
The combination of [time] and [box] is unique, so I can find one or zero record for that combination.

How could I check:

1) if two variables are inside of this array?, for example.

```
$varTime = '14:00';
$box = 3;
in_array($varTime+$box, $array2dimension) -> this is wrong, I don't know how to apply it
```

2) What is the position of this data? For example, in this sample, it will be [1]

Thanks in advance,
Felipe

Comment: If your array is obtained from the database, why do you not just add the conditions to the query, and check for a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can roll your own function, since as far as I know, `in_array` doesn't accept a custom comparator:

```
function inArr($arr2d, $targetTime, $targetBox) {
  foreach ($arr2d as $i => $e) {
    if ($e["time"] === $targetTime && $e["box"] === $targetBox) {
      return $i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

$array2dimension = [
  [
    "time" => "12:00",
    "box" => 3,
    "user" => "Laura"
  ],
  [
    "time" => "14:00",
    "box" => 3,
    "user" => "John"
  ]
];

echo inArr($array2dimension, "14:00", 3) . "\n";
echo inArr($array2dimension, "12:00", 3) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
PHP 7.0.8 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2016 23:39:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

1
0
```

Comment: Thank you so much ggorlen, it has been great help, regards :) works great

Answer (score 1):

Assume your `time` is `string`:

```
// what you are looking for
$time = '14:00';
$box = 3;

$found = 0;
$i = 0;

foreach($array2dimension as $row) {
    $time_i = $row['time'];
    $box_i = $row['box'];

    if ($time_i == $time && $box_i == $box) {
        $found = 1;
        break;
    }

    $i++;
}

if ($found == 1) {
    print "found in array element: $i";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$expected_values = array('time' => '14:00', 'box' => 3);

$found_elements = array_filter($array2dimension, function($sub_array) use ($expected_values) {
    $intersection_count = count(array_intersect_assoc($sub_array, $expected_values));

    return $intersection_count == count($expected_values);
});

if (!empty($found_elements)) {
    $found_indexes = array_keys($found_elements);
}
```

I hope the snippet will help you.

Comment: felt so free to change variable parts from `founded` to `found` because `founded` means something else ;-)